# Python Selenium Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to make a Python program that will automate login to my school's website. However, I'm returned with an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="loginidtext"]"}

The relevant code section throwing the error is:

```
BCnumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginidtext"]')
BCnumber.send_keys('loginid')
```

The website is:
 https://matrix.tjc.edu.sg/?topleft=toprow.php&bottomright=bottomrow.php

I've tried using:

```
driver.switch_to
```

to switch to the relevant div but the same error was returned...

Comment: that loginidtext field in inside the second frame. So, we need to switch to frame with index 1 and later sendkeys

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As the locator `//*[@id="loginidtext"]` is within `topwindow` iframe, we have to switch over to the iframe first as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://matrix.tjc.edu.sg/?topleft=toprow.php&bottomright=bottomrow.php')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.switch_to.frame("topwindow")
BCnumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginidtext"]')
BCnumber.send_keys('loginid')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Did you execute the code and check it whether it's working or not? because it's not working for me.

Comment: @RAJ Did you spot an error out there? Where do you see the error?
 Thanks

Comment: Element doesn't exist error was thrown! Did you execute the program and check it out? Is it passing for you?